# Make 3 phase motorcycle stator as engine starter

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, gate-driving

I've been studying this for more than a year. I want to make a BLDC controller to start a motorcycle engine, where the power source from a 12 V battery is input into the BLDC driver and then input to the 3 phase stator of the motorcycle which will turn the crankshaft and start the engine.

On several types of motorcycles in my area (Indonesia), they have this feature embedded in the ECU.

Normally when this driver is run it draws around 40 A @ 12 VDC.

When the driver is run for a while at 71 kHz, the gate driver IR2101 always crashes which causes the MOSFET to crash as well.

Can someone correct my schematic below?

[image: this is stator and rotor]

[image: this is schematic of driver]

```cpp
 void setup() {
      // INPUT DIGITAL SENSOR A
 pinMode(3, INPUT);
      // INPUT DIGITAL SENSOR B
 pinMode(4, INPUT);
      // INPUT DIGITAL SENSOR C
 pinMode(5, INPUT);
      // OUTPUT DIGITAL PHASE 1 (-)
 pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
      // OUTPUT DIGITAL PHASE 2 (-)
 pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
      // OUTPUT DIGITAL PHASE 3 (-)
 pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
      // OUTPUT PWM PHASE 1 (+)
 pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
     // OUTPUT PWM PHASE 2 (+)
 pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
      // OUTPUT PWM PHASE 3 (+)
 pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
    }
     void loop() { 
  TCCR1B = (TCCR1B & 0b11111000) | 2; //frequensi 3.9kHz
  TCCR2B = (TCCR2B & 0b11111000) | 2; // frequensi 3.9kHz        

 //step pengaman
if (digitalRead(3)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(4)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(5)==HIGH){

digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
                analogWrite(9,0);
                analogWrite(10,0);
                analogWrite(11,0);}}}
      
 //step pengaman
if (digitalRead(3)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(4)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(5)==LOW){

digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
                analogWrite(9,0);
                analogWrite(10,0);
                analogWrite(11,0);}}}
    
    
 //step1 (0)(-)(+) MAJU
if (digitalRead(3)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(4)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(5)==LOW){

digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
                analogWrite(9,0);
                analogWrite(10,0);
                analogWrite(11,250);}}}

    
 //step2 (+)(-)(0) MAJU
if (digitalRead(3)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(4)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(5)==HIGH){

digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
                analogWrite(9,250);
                analogWrite(10,0);
                analogWrite(11,0);}}}


 //step3 (+)(0)(-) MAJU
if (digitalRead(3)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(4)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(5)==HIGH){

digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
                analogWrite(9,250);
                analogWrite(10,0);
                analogWrite(11,0);}}}


 //step4 (0)(+)(-) MAJU
if (digitalRead(3)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(4)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(5)==HIGH){

digitalWrite(6,LOW);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
                analogWrite(9,0);
                analogWrite(10,250);
                analogWrite(11,0);}}}


 //step5 (-)(+)(0) MAJU
if (digitalRead(3)==LOW){
if (digitalRead(4)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(5)==LOW){

digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
                analogWrite(9,0);
                analogWrite(10,250);
                analogWrite(11,0);}}}

        

 //step6 (-)(0)(+) MAJU
if (digitalRead(3)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(4)==HIGH){
if (digitalRead(5)==LOW){

digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
                analogWrite(9,0);
                analogWrite(10,0);
                analogWrite(11,250);}}}
    
}// loop ends
```

Comment: Why 71kHZ, probably that's excessive. Try at lower freq. , start with 5kHz and so on.

Comment: Code is illegible in the comments. Please [edit] it into your question where it belongs. Please make sure that you use the `{}` code formatting button and that you have indented and commented properly.

Comment: how to set frequency on arduino code?
because I've written TCRR1B and TCRR2B at speed 2 (3.9khz), but why does the meter read 71k instead?
I measured on one of the lowside gate mosfet

Comment: Why are you posting code in the comments again? Please post it in your question and use the '{}' code formatting button. Indent and comment properly.

Comment: PWM controlled V(phase,frequency)  with V/RPM start ramp not max V at 0 RPM

Comment: I think this controller doesn't need speed control like rc car and others.

the point is i want the alternator to have enough torque to rotate for running the motorcycle engine and (ir2101) this driver mosfet is not damaged anymore when i run this driver